# C - Self-referencing structure and realloc

Tags: c, pointers, structure, realloc

I've got a problem with calling realloc on self-referencing structure. When I run this program, I get error `*** Error in ...: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000602160 ***`. I suppose the problem is related to the last line, because program runs without any problem if I comment it.

This is the smallest (not) working piece of code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct structure {
    int connections;
    struct structure *links;
} structure;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int struct_count;
    int i, from, to, offset;
    structure *structs;

    struct_count = 2;

    structs = malloc(sizeof(structure) * struct_count);
    memset(structs, 0, sizeof(structure) * struct_count);
    for(i = 0; i < struct_count; i++) {
        structs[i].links = malloc(1);
        structs[i].connections = 0;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        from = 0;
        to = 1;

        offset = structs[from].connections++;
        structs[from].links = realloc(structs[from].links, sizeof(int) * (offset + 1));
        structs[from].links[offset] = structs[to]; // This is the problematic line - why?
    }
}
```

And my question: what's wrong in that code?

Comment: `malloc(1)` is not enough for a pointer, this `structs[from].links = realloc(structs[from].links, sizeof(int) * (offset + 1));` is dangerous, `realloc()` could return `NULL` and the previous poitner would be gone thus causing a memory leak.

Comment: And why `sizeof(int)`  in your `realloc`? change to `sizeof(structure)`

Comment: "invalid next size" inevitably points out to some error that has happened prior to de-allocation or re-allocation. Run valgrind to see where the problem happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the first time you allocate it, it's not enough. To allocate `n` elements of a given type you can use

```
structs[i].links = malloc(n * sizeof(*structs[i].links));
```

and the same goes wit `realloc()` you also need to make sure that `realloc()` doesn't return `NULL`, suppose that after allocating space for `n` structures with the line above you want to resize to store `n + 1` instances, then

```
struct structure *links;
links = realloc(structs[i].links, (n + 1) * sizeof(*links));
if (links == NULL)
{
   /* Depending on the way your program is designed */
   probably_free_links(&structs[i].links);
   /*                  ^ make it `NULL' inside */
   allocation_failure_do_something_about_it_but_do_not_continue();
}
structs[i].links = links;
```

you can make `structs[i].links = NULL;` initially and `realloc()` will behave as `malloc()` the first time.

Write your programs as if all errors are possible, and do something about them don't just let your program invoke undefined behavior and make it a mistery to you and your program users.

Comment: "*Write your programs as if all errors are possible*" :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason why I didn't pass NULL to `realloc()` was that I got errors (Assertion failed), but that was another bug in my code. About error handling: This is only the smallest piece of code I was able to write that has this problem. I got valid pointers from `malloc()` and program crashed after THIRD pass through the loop.

Comment: This does a good job of explaining the error, but it misses that what the OP is actually doing is unlikely to be what he wants to do at all.  The naming suggest that instead of making multiple copies of the array elements, he wants to set up in each one a dynamic array of *pointers* to others.  In that case, the type of `structure.links` is wrong (should be `struct structure **`), and the assignments to it are also wrong.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think you are right, lets wait for feedback from the OP anyway.

Answer (score -1):

If You will increase the Blueprint of structure and decrease the size of loop it will run perfectly..

**For Example:-**without manipulating run your program just decrease the loop condition from 100 to 2. It will run perfectly.

If you want to increase loop size you have to increase the size of structure.